Software Updater does not open after upgrade to 24.04
Software Updater does not open after upgrade to 24.04.  I was on 23.10.
What steps should I take to further diagnose this?

Went to terminal and tried an apt update:sudo apt update
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu/ mantic: ....  dumped two public key blocks.......
E: The list of sources could not be read.

I had two entries in /etc/apt/sources.list.d for mozilla:
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10127 May 22 14:07 mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-kinetic.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9908 May 22 14:07 mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-mantic.sources

I removed the kinetic entry and sudo apt update works now.
Software Updater now opens and works.
Also found a lot of old and unused files in the directory that I removed.  This is the list prior to the cleanup:
steve@SteveLaptop:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ ls -l
total 216
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Jan 28  2021 aheck-ubuntu-ppa-groovy.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Jan 28  2021 aheck-ubuntu-ppa-groovy.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Jan  4  2021 codeblocks-devs-ubuntu-daily-groovy.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Jan  4  2021 codeblocks-devs-ubuntu-daily-groovy.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Jan  4  2021 codeblocks-devs-ubuntu-release-groovy.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Jan  4  2021 codeblocks-devs-ubuntu-release-groovy.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   223 May 22 13:22 google-chrome.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   191 Jun  8  2023 google-chrome.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 15448 May 22 14:07 google-chrome.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 15448 May 22 14:07 google-chrome.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   103 May 22 13:22 inkscape_dev-ubuntu-stable-groovy.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    68 Jun  8  2023 inkscape_dev-ubuntu-stable-groovy.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   747 May 22 14:07 inkscape_dev-ubuntu-stable-groovy.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   747 May 22 14:07 inkscape_dev-ubuntu-stable-groovy.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Oct 24  2022 jtaylor-ubuntu-keepass-eoan.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   130 Oct 23  2022 jtaylor-ubuntu-keepass-eoan.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Oct 24  2022 jtaylor-ubuntu-keepass-eoan.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Oct 24  2022 kg7je-ubuntu-gnc-released-ppa-bionic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   148 Oct 23  2022 kg7je-ubuntu-gnc-released-ppa-bionic.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Oct 24  2022 kg7je-ubuntu-gnc-released-ppa-bionic.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Apr 20  2023 malteworld-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    63 Apr 20  2023 malteworld-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Apr 20  2023 malteworld-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   107 May 22 13:22 mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-kinetic.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    72 Jun  8  2023 mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-kinetic.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10127 May 22 14:07 mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-kinetic.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10127 May 22 14:07 mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-kinetic.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9908 May 22 14:07 mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-mantic.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9908 May 22 09:20 mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-mantic.sources.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9908 May 22 14:07 mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-mantic.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  8367 May 22 14:07 oibaf-ubuntu-graphics-drivers-mantic.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  8369 May 22 09:20 oibaf-ubuntu-graphics-drivers-mantic.sources.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  8367 May 22 14:07 oibaf-ubuntu-graphics-drivers-mantic.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Oct 24  2022 phoerious-ubuntu-keepassxc-eoan.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   138 Oct 23  2022 phoerious-ubuntu-keepassxc-eoan.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Oct 24  2022 phoerious-ubuntu-keepassxc-eoan.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Oct 24  2022 subsurface-ubuntu-subsurface-bionic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    69 Oct 23  2022 subsurface-ubuntu-subsurface-bionic.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Oct 24  2022 subsurface-ubuntu-subsurface-bionic.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Apr 20  2023 teejee2008-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    63 Apr 20  2023 teejee2008-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Apr 20  2023 teejee2008-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Jan 24  2021 thopiekar-ubuntu-miraclecast-groovy.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Jan 24  2021 thopiekar-ubuntu-miraclecast-groovy.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Apr 20  2023 ubuntuhandbook1-ubuntu-avidemux-focal.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    74 Apr 20  2023 ubuntuhandbook1-ubuntu-avidemux-focal.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Apr 20  2023 ubuntuhandbook1-ubuntu-avidemux-focal.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Apr 10  2023 ubuntu-mozilla-security-ubuntu-ppa-groovy.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    76 Oct 23  2022 ubuntu-mozilla-security-ubuntu-ppa-groovy.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Apr 10  2023 ubuntu-mozilla-security-ubuntu-ppa-groovy.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   385 May 22 14:07 ubuntu.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   385 May 22 14:07 ubuntu.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   164 May 22 14:07 winehq-mantic.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   164 May 22 09:20 winehq-mantic.sources.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   164 May 22 14:07 winehq-mantic.sources.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Apr 20  2023 wireshark-dev-ubuntu-stable-eoan.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    67 Apr 20  2023 wireshark-dev-ubuntu-stable-eoan.list.distUpgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Apr 20  2023 wireshark-dev-ubuntu-stable-eoan.list.save

The list after the cleanup:
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 15448 May 22 14:07 google-chrome.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   747 May 22 14:07 inkscape_dev-ubuntu-stable-groovy.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9908 May 22 14:07 mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-mantic.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  8367 May 22 14:07 oibaf-ubuntu-graphics-drivers-mantic.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   385 May 22 14:07 ubuntu.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   164 May 22 14:07 winehq-mantic.sources


Try this, it should fix your problem:
sudo apt install update-manager

The same thing happened to me, and that's how I diagnosed the issue :) .
